# how to open gmail and send email to specific id in a android app?

Tags: android

how to open gmail and send email to specific id ina android app?

```
               Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
               startActivity(emailIntent);
```

but its not working for me ActivityNotFoundException is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work. Try on a real device.

Comment: Is it necessary to use: 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine and yes its working fine here in real device. I am sure you are trying to test the same on Emulator, instead try the same in real device.